# How to do this using JOIN

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables.

```
tbl_person:
  - person_id
  - unique_id_number

tbl_plan:
  - plan_id
  - plan_name

tbl_person_plan:
  - id
  - person_id
  - plan_id
  - is_done

tbl_monitor_level:
  - id
  - unique_id_number
  - sugar_level
  - date_submitted
```

Users will input data everyday in tbl_monitor_level. I just want to retrieve all unique_id_number where they haven't inputted any data for today.

I use this

```
select distinct tml.unique_id_number, count(tml.sugar_level) from 
tbl_person tp
right join
tbl_monitor_level tml on 
tml.unique_id_number = tp.unique_id_number
inner join tbl_person_plan tpp on 
tpp.person_id = tp.person_id
where tml.date_submitted = '2013-01-08'
group by tml.unique_id_number
```

but it will only get all the unique_id_number with a date_submitted = 2003-01-08
I want to get this instead

```
unique_id_number | count
-------------------------
G12345A          |   1
G23456B          |   0
```

But as it is it will not get the other `unique_id_number (G23456B)`. All these `unique_id_numbers` exist on other tables.

Sample data

```
 tbl_person
    - person_id - 1
    - unique_id_number - G12345A

    - person_id - 2
    - unique_id_number - G23456B

 tbl_plan
    - plan_id - 1
    - plan_name - Plan A

 tbl_person_plan
    - id - 1
    - person_id - 1
    - plan_id - 1
    - is_done - 0 

    - id - 2
    - person_id - 2
    - plan_id - 1
    - is_done - 0

 tbl_monitor_level
    - id - 1
    - unique_id_number - G12345A
    - sugar_level - 100
    - date_submitted - 2013-01-08

    - id - 2
    - unique_id_number - G12345B
    - sugar_level - 200
    - date_submitted - 2013-01-07
```

The above data should be the result. But I am getting only

```
unique_id_number | count
-------------------------
G12345A          |   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A LEFT JOIN should get this for you as follows:

```
SELECT tp.unique_id_number, COUNT(tml.id) AS count
FROM tbl_person tp
LEFT JOIN tbl_monitor_level tml
  ON tp.unique_id_number = tml.unique_id_number
  AND tml.date_submitted = '2013-01-08'
GROUP BY tp.unique_id_number
```

The primary difference is the LEFT vs RIGHT JOIN that you did, and that you need to group on the table that always has an entry - `tbl_person` in this case.  Also, the WHERE clause needs to be merged into the LEFT JOIN itself to avoid excluding entries without matching monitor rows.

Here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76b88/2) of it working.

```
UNIQUE_ID_NUMBER | COUNT
G12345A          | 1      
G23456B          | 0
```

Just FYI, RIGHT JOINs are scarcely used as they usually serve to make the SQL logic more confusing than it already is ;)

Comment: @jantox: Actually, I forgot to address the WHERE filter issue - updated.  Does that work for you?

Comment: this will produce given the above example. number-G12345A count-1 and number-G23456B count-1. should have been number-G12345A count-1 and number-G23456B count-0

Comment: @jantox: You are right - fixed with sqlfiddle showing the results you want.